# return template interpolation within ternary operator in angular 5

Tags: angular5, string-interpolation, angular-template

How do achieve following in angular 5 template:

```
<h6>{{userWalletData.BTCWalletBalance ? {{userWalletData.BTCWalletBalance}} BTC = {{userWalletData.BTCWalletBalanceInFiat}} : 'Fetching balance...'}}</h6>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Angular's *ngIf in the template to achieve it.

```
<h6 *ngIf="userWalletData.BTCWalletBalance != undefined && userWalletData.BTCWalletBalanceInFiat != undefined; else fetching_balance">{{userWalletData.BTCWalletBalance}} BTC = {{userWalletData.BTCWalletBalanceInFiat}}</h6>

<ng-template #fetching_balance><span>Fetching balance...</span></ng-template>
```

hope it helps!